# Best way to handle connection string and primar key for Azure Function when created with ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

What are best practices for :

- managing app settings
- including connection string-access key for    other resources
  inside/outside of the resource group?

Some of the examples utilize using listKeys function inside templates, but I'm wondering if there is better way of doing this, especially, when I need to include resource access keys outside of my subscription and resource group.

Also, the example utilizes concat functino, is there a way to retrieve the whole connectionstring-access key string from the resource directly? or maybe store them inside keyvault of external paramters file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice is to use the functions (list*, reference), here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#resource-functions

They will work across subscriptions provided you have the full resourceId passed in.

For the other questions, it would help to see the code you're thinking about to provide advice...

Answer (score 0):

In terms of managing app settings, I think it would depends on what type of settings you are referring, is it sensitive? Do you want it to be securely stored?

If the key is sensitive to your business requirement, then it wouldn't be suitable for having it directly in your function app in plaintext, what you could do is to use `listkeys` to retrieve keys  while provisoning your keyvault and then get them in runtime from your function probably is better approach.